# List Data from Java-EE bean file is not showing up in JSF XHTML DataTable element

Tags: html, jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml

Here are the steps of how many application currently works:

1.User Registers as a Voter using a form.

2.When user submits the form the data gets saved into a bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class VoterBean implements Serializable{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
 private String city;
 private String state;
 private String zip;
    private String phone;
    private String affil;

    public VoterBean(){

    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

 public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

 public String getState(){
        return state;
    }

 public String getZip(){
        return zip;
    }


    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAffil(){
        return affil;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }


  public void setCity(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

  public void setState(String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

  public void setZip(String zip){
        this.zip = zip;
    }   

    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setAffil(String affil){
        this.affil = affil;
    }


}
```

3.In addition when the form is submitted the information from the above bean is saved to another Bean in a List variable:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.*;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class VoterData implements Serializable{

 private VoterBean voter = new VoterBean();

     private List<VoterBean> voterList = new ArrayList<VoterBean>();

     public VoterData(){
     }

     public List<VoterBean> getVoterList() {
          return voterList;
     }

     public String saveRegistration(){
         voterList.add(voter);
         return "VoterList";  
     }


}
```

The above class' meethod is called with the Submit button on the form page:

```
<h:commandButton id = "Yes" value = "Yes" action = "#{voterData.saveRegistration}"/><br/>
```

4.After info from the first bean is saved into the List Variable in the 2nd bean, the user is taken to a JSF XHTML page that shows all the current users who have registered in a DataTable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html  
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <title>Voter Summary</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>


      <h:form id = "form" >

      <h:outputLabel value = "First Name:"/> 
     <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.firstName}"    /> 
<br/>

 <h:outputLabel value = "Last Name:"/> 
       <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.lastName}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "Address:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.address}"/>

<br/>
 <h:outputLabel value = "City:"/> 
     <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.city}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "State"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.state}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "Zip:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.zip}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "Phone:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.phone}"/>
<br/>

 <h:outputLabel value = "Affiliation:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterBean.affil}"/>
<br/>

Is the following information correct?
<br/>
       <h:commandButton id = "Yes" value = "Yes" action = "#{voterData.saveRegistration}"/><br/>
      <h:commandButton id = "No" value = "No" action = "Register"/><br/>
      </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

However here comes the PROBLEM:

The Data from the List isn't showing up on the HTML page even after I registered one voter. it just shows the column Names but no data.

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.. am I adding the information correctly? Am I reading in the information incorrectly?

Comment: Please note that the `VoterBean` is just POJO (simple java class with fields +getters/setters), and it shouldn't be _considered_ (annotated) as managed bean. Remove the two annotations above the `VoterBean` class.

Comment: Are you trying to use the VoterBean you created with ` private VoterBean voter = new VoterBean();`? That's not a managed bean and it won't be available for use on your page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
<h:outputLabel value = "Address:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterData.voter.address}"/>

<br/>
 <h:outputLabel value = "City:"/> 
     <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterData.voter.city}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "State"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterData.voter.state}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "Zip:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterData.voter.zip}"/>
<br/>


 <h:outputLabel value = "Phone:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterData.voter.phone}"/>
<br/>

 <h:outputLabel value = "Affiliation:"/> 
      <h:outputLabel value = "#{voterData.voter.affil}"/>
```

You are trying to make a change to the Original object.
you want to access your voterData property voter which is the type of voterBean.